# How to pass Two or more parameters using XSL attribute

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I m calling a javascript function through xsl using  like this:

```
    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
     <xsl:text>Toggle(</xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="$i"/>
     <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
```

and the function is this:

```
    function Toggle(ID)
     {
        ------
     }
```

what if I have to pass two parameters instead??
viz. how can I call this function??

```
    function Toggle(ID1, ID2)
    {
      -----
    }
```

Currently i m doing this:

```
    <xsl:attribute name="onclick" xmlns:xsl="#unknown">
      <xsl:text>Toggle(</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$i" /> 
      <xsl:text>,ID)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
```

Is this right???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass in a string literal in Javascript then you can enclose it in single quotes thus if you want to pass in the string constant `foo` you would use

```
<xsl:attribute name="onclick">
  <xsl:text>Toggle(</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="$i" /> 
  <xsl:text>, 'foo')</xsl:text>
</xsl:attribute>
```

I would check whether a literal result element and an attribute value template does not allow you to write that more compact and readable, for instance

```
<input type="button" onclick="Toggle({$i}, 'foo');"/>
```

if you want to have an `onclick` attribute on an `input` element.

Comment: Oh! Literal quotes, that what I was missing I guess.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If ID1 and ID2 represent variables (as you illustrated with ID), it probably would be something like this, assuming `$1` and `$2` are variables:

```
<xsl:attribute name="onclick" xmlns:xsl="#unknown">
      <xsl:text>Toggle(</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$i1" /> 
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$i2" />
      <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: No, ID2 is static, I have to pass some static char into the function. Basically that char will be appended to the ID1 to make it unique.

Comment: XSLT just generates the text. Unless you have to generate that text dinamically (passing different data to the XSL processor to generate a different string), you don't need to have variables. Any `$n` you declare means that somewhere in your XSL you either have a `<xsl:variable name="n" />` or `<xsl:param name="n" />`. Params receive data from outside the stylesheet.